# Holding spots for UEFA Champions league

Tags: football, uefa

Looking at the last season's standing after last fixture of the season, How is it decided that

- England will have top *4* teams qualifying for UEFA Champions League, *3* teams qualifying for UEFA Europa League
- Spain will have top *5* teams qualifying for UEFA Champions League, *2* teams qualifying for UEFA Europa League
- Italy will have top *3* teams qualifying for UEFA Champions League, *3* teams qualifying for UEFA Europa League
- Germany will have top *4* teams qualifying for UEFA Champions League, *2* teams qualifying for UEFA Europa League
- France will have top *3* teams qualifying for UEFA Champions League, *1* team qualifying for UEFA Europa League

I am not sure if this question is a duplicate of [Who decides how are UEFA competitions spots divided within teams in some country?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/4433/7509)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who decides how are UEFA competitions spots divided within teams in some country?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4433/who-decides-how-are-uefa-competitions-spots-divided-within-teams-in-some-country)

Comment: @PhilipKendall: I did mention that in the question itself.

Comment: With all due respect, I tend to disagree that it is a duplicate. I believe the question that you pointed at, is more about how the spots are divided within the *same* country. I am asking about how it is decided that England gets 4, while France gets 3 spots to fill in for UEFA Champions league. But anyways, close it off if you feel so. That's how Stack Exchange works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding onto Mujtaba's answer, **it's not just the Champions League performance that matters but the Europa league performance too**. UEFA calculates a country's coefficient rankings based on their performance in the last 5 years in both competitions.

The exact details as to how the coefficient is calculated is posted on [UEFA's site](http://www.uefa.com/memberassociations/news/newsid=1592808.html#how+five+year+country+rankings+calculated).

Answer (score 1):

The top 3 ranked countries get 4 spots and the next 3 get 3 and next 9 get 2 and remaining get 1 spot in the uefa champions league. As for the ranking of the countries it will be based on how the teams from that countries performed in the last 5 editions of the champions league 
EX:for 2015-16 season Seasons from 2009-10 to 2013-14 performances are taken into account.

Answer (score -4):

No country ever gets five representatives ,the maximum is four for the three highest ranked countries.You can get more information by clicking this link      http://www.uefa.com/memberassociations/uefarankings/country/

Comment: Wrong, it is possible. Spain got 5 because Sevilla won the Europa League and thus winning a spot in the Champions League the next, current at this time, season. Real, Atletico Madrid, Barcelona, Sevilla and Valencia are playing CL this season.

Comment: Another example of 5 teams playing in the Champions League from the same country is in the 2005/06 season. Liverpool won the 2004/05 Champions League, but finished 5th in the Premier League table. There was initially alot of controversy as Everton had finished 4th, and UEFA asked FA to choose between Everton or Liverpool to play in the CL since its rules back then restricted the maximum number of teams in the CL from one country to four, leaving it to the country's FA to decide which team to allow. FA said it would give Everton the final English spot. (continued in next comment)

Comment: Following pressure from fans and former footballers alike, UEFA agreed to allow Liverpool to defend its title, thus granting England five spots in the CL, with both Everton and Liverpool having to come through the qualifying rounds. UEFA subsequently amended its rules. Currently, if a team wins the CL but does not within the qualifying spots in the league table, the team in the last qualifying spot is not allowed into the CL, but has to play in the Europa League.